# Laravel - Foreach value in php tags with blade template

Tags: function, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade, steam

I have trouble with that, let me explain.
In controller, I get users.

```
$users = User::where('steamid','!=','')->orderBy('time','DESC')->get();
```

After that in Blade template I need to use PHP function for the get steam profile link from steam id.

I have a function:

```
function SteamName($steamid){
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/$steamid/?xml=1");//link to user xmla
    $username = $xml->steamID;
    return $username;
}
```

I have a `foreach` for every user:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
//so, i need to do like this;
<?php print SteamName($user->steamid) ?>
@endforeach
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Please describe what error you get and what you expect the end result to be.

Comment: I cant see errors but i need to use this {{$user->steamid}} in a function in php tags. So, i cant use it like this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your function inside User Model

```
function SteamName($steamid){
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/$steamid/?xml=1");//link to user xmla
    $username = $xml->steamID;
    return $username;
}
```

From Your blade call the function :

```
@foreach($users as $user)
{{ $user->SteamName($user->steamid) }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you! I fixed it. Love you.

Comment: Addendum: Judging from your use case, you may also like to look into Laravel's model accessors. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) ... You could make a method `getSteamUsernameAttribute()` in which you define your logic. Then the output will be available as `$user->steam_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
{{$user->steamid}}
@endforeach
```